# can you exactly recreate 'histeq' results in matlab without using the histeq function?

Tags: image, matlab, histogram

i am trying to carry out manual histogram equalization and get an accurate result. i have created some code that gives me a fairly good equalized image however it is not an exact replica of the 'histeq' result. i am wondering what is needed to get an exact replica of the histeq function without directly using it?

i tried the following code for histogram equalisation but doesnt not give an identical image to 'histeq':

```matlab
clc, clearvars;

x = imread('mri_001.JPG');
[V, B] = hist(double(x(:)), [0:255]);
subplot(2, 3, 1);
bar(B, V),
xlabel('intensity'), ylabel('No. of pixels')

y = imread('mri_001.JPG');
normalise = numel(y);
[N, C] = hist(double(y(:)), [0:255]);
N = N / normalise;
subplot(2, 3, 2);
bar(C, N),
xlabel('intensity'), ylabel('Normalised freq.')

z = imread('mri_001.JPG');
normalise = numel(z);
[O, D] = hist(double(z(:)), [0:255]);
O = O / normalise;
M = cumsum(O);
subplot(2, 3, 3);
bar(D, M),
xlabel('cumulative intensity'), ylabel('Normalised freq.')

Out = uint8(255 * M(z + 1));
[P, E] = hist(double(Out(:)), [0:255]);
subplot(2, 3, 4);
bar(E, P),
xlabel('manual histeq')

k = imread('mri_001.JPG');
L = histeq(k);
[Q, F] = hist(double(L(:)), [0:255]);
subplot(2, 3, 5);
bar(F, Q),
xlabel('matlab histeq funct')

figure, imshow(Out) % manual histeq
figure, imshow(L) % matlab histeq
figure, imshow(x) % original
```

Comment: What does the 256 bin histogram of the Matlab equalised (and your DIY one) actually look like? Or the test images for that matter? I suspect that Matlab might replace binned together values with the weighted average of the contributing bins (but that is only a guess) based on what I would expect histogram equalisation to do - usually in my case from 1024 (or more) grey levels down to 256 for display on a PC.

Comment: The MATLAB documentation says that `histeq` uses [64 bins](https://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/histeq.html#d126e129119) by default. It also gives the [algorithm](https://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/histeq.html#bvhend8-1) used to calculate the target histogram. I haven't checked, but it's likely that you can actually see the code that MATLAB uses for `histeq` by editing the file `histeq.m`.

Comment: the histograms when compared are relatively close however there are some slight visible differences. this is the same with the actual out put image. the image from my function appears to have lighter pixels in dark areas compared to the image that used the histeq function. nothing major but noticeable when side by side. when using only 64 bins the histograms become almost identical, how would i then carry this into my output image?